# Extract 2 different Json input using one JoltTrasformJson in NIFI

Tags: arrays, json, apache-nifi

How can I configure the JoltTransformJson processor to get the above output? Or is there any other ways to do it? Please advise with step and example. appreciate.

There are two input Json:

1st Json input:

```
{ "Name" : "Alvin", "Status" : "Single", "Life" : [ { "Sport" : "Swimming", "Singing" : "K-box", "Singing" : "K-box", "Food" : "Burger", "Alcohol" : "Rum" }, { "Sport" : "Boxing", "Singing" : "party world", "Food" : "Chicken Wing", "Alcohol" : "Whisky" }, { "Sport" : "Running", "Singing" : "KTV", "Food" : "Muffin",  "Alcohol" : "Martel" }] }
```

2nd Json input:

```
{"Name" : "Alvin", "Status" : "Single", "Life" : { "Sport" : "Swimming", "Singing" : "K-box", "Food" : "Burger", "Alcohol" : "Rum" } }
```

This two Json message input should go to a same JoltTransformJson processor and come out with the following output:

1st Json output:

```
{ "Name" : "Alvin", "Status" : "Single", "Sport" : [ "Swimming", "Boxing", "Running"], "Singing" : [ "K-box", "party world" , "KTV"], "Alcohol" : [ "Rum", "Whisky", "Martel"] }
```

2nd Json output:

```
{ "Name" : "Alvin", "Status" : "Single", "Sport" : [ "Swimming"], "Singing" : [ "K-box"], "Food" : [ "Burger"], "Alcohol" : ["Rum"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on similar casestudy and i have used below method which worked perfectly

EvaluateJsonPath --> mergerecord (you need to specify avro scheme) -->  AttributesToJSON

[image]